# Django 'User' object has no attribute 'phone'

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to add a custom field called `phone` but I get this error:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'phone'
```

What I did in `models.py` is:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=17, null=True, unique=True)
    ...

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

and I have `forms.py`

```
class CreatUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']
```

and finally in `views.py` I have the following function:

```
@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreatUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            group = Group.objects.get(name='customers')
            user.groups.add(group)
            first_name = user.first_name
            last_name =  user.last_name
            email = user.email
            phone = user.phone

            Customer.objects.create(
                user=user, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, phone=phone,
            )
        
            messages.success(request, username + ' created!')
            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'main/page-register.html', context)
```

But I can't get `phone` from my users!

Comment: The model is a *user*, not a customer...

Comment: I need to sync `Customer` and `User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely better to work with *two* forms here, one for the `User`, and one for the `Customer`, and then "link" the two at the view level:

```
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message='Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.')
    phone = forms.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['phone']
```

then we can combine both forms with:

```
@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form2 = CustomerForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            form2.instance.user = user
            form2.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='customers')
            user.groups.add(group)
            messages.success(request, username + ' created!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        form2 = CustomerForm()
    context = {'form': form, 'form2': forom2}
    return render(request, 'main/page-register.html', context)
```

in the template, then both forms are rendered:

```
<form action="…" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1 }}
    {{ form2 }}
    Create customer
</form>
```

Your customer should *not* have the same fields as the user: you are then *duplicating* data, and it is hard to keep data in sync.

Comment: Great, Thank you very much. I can also pass other field from my models.